# Issue with activemq on starting

Tags: exception, activemq-classic

I had been using activemq without any issues. Now when I am trying to start activemq using the command `activemq start` from the command window, it is throwing an error.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/act
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
>           at 
>            java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>           at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)

I am using jdk version 7.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong JDK/JRE version.

The exception `java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError` is always a pointer to this problem.

You have to update your JDK/JRE.

Comment: I was using the same activemq and jdk. Since it was working fine, can that be the reason?

Comment: I can only tell you what the concrete exception says and it says you need an upgrade. Have you changed anything else (e.g. some supporting library)?

Comment: I haven't changed anything. Is it necessary to set the environment variables for java_home for this? Because previously, i hadn't set those things. But few days back, I set the enivronment variables with jdk7 paths.

Comment: I just deleted the java_home variables which were set for some other purpose. Now activemq got started.  Anyways thankyou @Uwe Plonus